# ASP.NET MVC DRY

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a project which has Area called Admin. There is a class called MenuTab with code logic which is used in Admin Area Master page and on the root Master page. Now I want admin Area to fully decoupled and not rely on root pages/code.

Should I create MenuTab class for Admin Area and another for root pages so that when I remove Admin area from project to use it somewhere else work smoothly OR keep MenuTab class at the root level and use it everywhere. What approach should I use?

Hope you understand my question.

How can I make Admin area independent?

Comment: maybe you want to move MenuTab to it's own assembly and let root and admin depend on it?

Comment: Adding new Class Library project and moving common code there to use in different places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a common assembly which all of your other web projects inherit from.

This is pretty common practice.

Comment: Onething What about the Javascript files that are common to all?